# Change statusbar onmouseover in a DIV

Tags: javascript, html, onclick, onmouseover

I've a DIV as a button using onclick and want to change the statusbar information shown using onmouseover.

But it doesn't work:

```
<div id="button1" onclick="location.href='LINK'" onmouseover="window.status='LINK'" onmouseout="window.status=''">
```

Is there any special I've missed?

Comment: What doesn't work? "location.href='LINK'" is probably meaningless -- do you really have a URI that's named 'LINK'? The onmouseover/out part works for me. You sure your browser isn't set to prevent status bar changes?

Comment: @squidbe: I think it's pretty clear that "LINK" is a placeholder for the question's purposes.

Comment: Ok, maybe its my FF 4 blocking JS on status bar. LINK means I have a normal link there like http://bla.bla.com/folder1/action2/bla.php?param1=2

But I thought, LINK is easier to read ;)

Comment: @Tomalak, ah, well it wasn't clear to me at the time. :-) In any event, I'm betting his problem is/was browser settings.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unless there is something else going on that you are not telling us about, you are mimicking the behavior of a normal link.  You should just use a <a href> link instead of a div.  It's easy to style a link to look like a button with a little CSS.

The reason you don't see the changes you are trying to make to the status bar is because modern browsers block JavaScript from making changes to the status bar. They now do this because the technique you are using has been used in the past to make deceptive links.

Comment: Oh, I would use <a href ... if I could.
But could I put some other Divs for Icons, TitleText of the "button", subtitle text etc. in a <a href...> ... </a> environment?

Comment: @Konrad, the devil is in the details, but you could do practically anything via CSS using span tags within your a tag (div tags will probably work, but span will keep it valid).